# Enter only eight letters in text box

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a textbox named date. I need to enter only 8 letters in that textbox with out using validation. Is it possible? How? Please help

Comment: You mean, like using the `maxlength` attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set the `maxlength=` attribute on the `<input...` tag.

Here's a good reference on the tag and attribute: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmltextfields.php

Answer (score 4):

```
<textarea name='date' maxlength='8'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript validation to enter only 8 letters in that textbox.

```
function validate(){
        x=document.myForm
        input=x.myInput.value
        if (input.length>8){
            alert("The field cannot contain more than 5 characters!")
            return false
        }else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

You can see demo [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/Validateanfieldwithamaximumnumberofcharacters.htm)